# flash data initialization by C compiler

Tags: gcc, arm, c99

I have some data stored in a flash. This data has to be encapsulated within a single file so it is static.

```
static const int my_array[1024];
static const int my_example[] = { -1, -1, -1};
```

The first line does everything I need except writing 0 for every element of this array. It is flash, so I would like to initialize it to -1 (0xFFFFFFFF). Of course, I can initialize every element individually exactly how line 2 does but my array has quite a lot of data.

Is it possible to do what I want for ARMCC and GNU using C99?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Macros to the rescue:

```
#define FILL4 -1, -1, -1, -1
#define FILL16 FILL4, FILL4, FILL4, FILL4
#define FILL64 FILL16, FILL16, FILL16, FILL16
#define FILL256 FILL64, FILL64, FILL64, FILL64
static const int my_array[1024] = {FILL256, FILL256, FILL256, FILL256};
```

Comment: I think you meant FILL256 in the last line yes?

Comment: This is a workaround. Could be done in many ways. Not the answer to my question.

Comment: @Submin then I must not understand the question. What sort of answer are you looking for, if this doesn't qualify? What aspect of this one do you find unsatisfactory?

Comment: Yuri, you did understand my question and you have suggested a workaround. Seems that there is no other way to force the compiler to initialize the whole array with anything else but 0. Googling this issue I did see syntaxis like [100] = [{0,...50] = 0xFF,]. Neither compiler understood it.  Tried to find it again for posting it here but unfortunately was unable to.  Spasibo.